# ipdb / set_trace() bug on Windows?

Tags: python, ipdb

I am getting a really strange output when running a python script and setting a break point with ipdb as in this program:

```
import sys
import ipdb
parents, babies = (1, 1)
while babies < 100:
    ipdb.set_trace()
    print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
    ipdb.set_trace()
    parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies)
```

It all works fine when running the script at first, stopping at the first break point and printing all the variables. But as soon as I approach the second break point where it doesn't matter if I step through it or just continue, I get these kind of weird characters as output in the console:

```
C:\pythontest>python ipdb_test2.py
> c:\pythontest\ipdb_test2.py(6)<module>()
      5         ipdb.set_trace()
----> 6         print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
      7         ipdb.set_trace()

ipdb> n
This generation has 1 babies
> c:\pythontest\ipdb_test2.py(7)<module>()
      6         print 'This generation has {0} babies'.format(babies)
----> 7         ipdb.set_trace()
      8         parents, babies = (babies, parents + babies)

ipdb> n
> ←[1;32mc:\pythontest\ipdb_test2.py←[0m(8)←[0;36m<module>←[1;34m()←[0m
←[1;32m      6 ←[1;33m        ←[1;32mprint←[0m ←[1;34m'This generation has {0} b
abies'←[0m←[1;33m.←[0m←[0mformat←[0m←[1;33m(←[0m←[0mbabies←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m←[1;33
m←[0m←[0m
←[0m←[1;32m      7 ←[1;33m        ←[0mipdb←[0m←[1;33m.←[0m←[0mset_trace←[0m←[1;3
3m(←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
←[0m←[1;32m----> 8 ←[1;33m        ←[0mparents←[0m←[1;33m,←[0m ←[0mbabies←[0m ←[1
;33m=←[0m ←[1;33m(←[0m←[0mbabies←[0m←[1;33m,←[0m ←[0mparents←[0m ←[1;33m+←[0m ←[
0mbabies←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
←[0m
ipdb> n
> ←[1;32mc:\pythontest\ipdb_test2.py←[0m(4)←[0;36m<module>←[1;34m()←[0m
←[1;32m      3 ←[1;33m←[0mparents←[0m←[1;33m,←[0m ←[0mbabies←[0m ←[1;33m=←[0m ←[
1;33m(←[0m←[1;36m1←[0m←[1;33m,←[0m ←[1;36m1←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
←[0m←[1;32m----> 4 ←[1;33m←[1;32mwhile←[0m ←[0mbabies←[0m ←[1;33m<←[0m ←[1;36m10
0←[0m←[1;33m:←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
←[0m←[1;32m      5 ←[1;33m        ←[0mipdb←[0m←[1;33m.←[0m←[0mset_trace←[0m←[1;3
3m(←[0m←[1;33m)←[0m←[1;33m←[0m←[0m
←[0m
ipdb>
```

As soon as I hit the ipdb.set_trace() command the second time it will output these kind of characters and from that point on the debugger becomes unusable. I tried it on different consoles but the error seems to persist.

I am using Python 2.7.8 with Anaconda 2.1.0 (64 bit) on Windows, any ideas how to solve this problem are warmly welcomed.

Comment: is there any reason why you're using ipdb? pdb works fine for me.

Comment: True but ipdb was recommended to me by a friend to be more versatile. I also prefer the default coloring of ipdb than the plain black white output of pdb, also no intendation is done by pdb.
It does work when calling "python -m ipdb ipdb_test2.py" and setting breakpoints interactively. I find this a bit cumbersome though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strange output are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). That's how ipdb does syntax highlighting. However CMD windows don't support the escape codes by default, it's been that way since DOS days. You have to enable a special driver named [ANSI.SYS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI.SYS) for the control codes to work. ipdb must be pulling some kind of magic that breaks the second time you call set_trace().

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! However on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI.SYS#Occurrence) it says there is no ANSI.SYS file present starting from Windows 7 anymore. 
Also now on Windows 10 I do not experience this error anymore. I am not quite sure if that's only because of OS change, but I don't think I changed any other configurations.

Comment: Anyhow, your answer is helpful since the problem is about ANSI escape codes which are indeed supported now for the first time in a Win32 console in Windows 10 (according to your wikipedia link). In previous versions of Windows you would need to enable this driver manually. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score -1):

The normal approach for using `ipdb` (and `pdb` as far as I know) is to only set one `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` command in your code where you want to break into the debugger. From there you can set other breakpoints, using the [`break` or `b` command](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break) and then pressing `continue` or `c` to get to that breakpoint. Consider this simple `pdb` session for example:

```
➜  python  python hello.py
hello
> /Users/kermit/Dropbox/dev/skripte/python/hello.py(4)<module>()
-> print('hello 2')
(Pdb) l
  1     print('hello')
  2     import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
  3
  4  -> print('hello 2')
  5     print('hello 3')
[EOF]
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at /Users/kermit/Dropbox/dev/skripte/python/hello.py:5
(Pdb) c
hello 2
> /Users/kermit/Dropbox/dev/skripte/python/hello.py(5)<module>()
-> print('hello 3')
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Ok that's possible of course. But what if I want to set a breakpoint in a loop and check the value of a variable in each iteration? Then when i insert the line `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` within the loop I have the same problem, as I'm approaching the line the second time. I know the problem does not occur with pdb but I really prefer the output style of ipdb

Comment: so what I would do then would be to insert `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` just before the loop, once inside the debugger use the `break` command to insert another breakpoint dynamically that is within the loop and then `continue` at will to inspect the state at every iteration.

Comment: Ok that's a good workaround. I will continue using ipdb now like this, but still interested what actually causes this output, which seems to be ipdb specific. When I have more time I will dig into this problem further.